# Way to get all custom labels?

Tags: apex

Is there any way to get all custom labels in an org?

Say I have something like this in a controller

```
public Map<String,String> getCustomLabels() {

    customLabels = [get all labels]

    return customLabels
}
```

or is there a method to get them through a SOQL query?

Answer (score 9):

Custom labels are not accessible via SOQL. You will need to use the Metadata API to complete the query you are looking for.

I would suggest taking a look at Andrew Fawcett's [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

With the API you can query the [CustomLabels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm) metadata type to get the information you are looking for.