# Get a map of all custom labels

Tags: apex, visualforce, customlabel

Is it possible to get a map, in either Apex or using visualforce remoting, of all custom labels? If not does anyone know of the easiest way to access custom labels from javascript?

Right now we have a 1000 line long visualforce js page that is mainly for defining custom labels as javascript objects and it would be nice if we could shorten that code a bit.

Comment: Duplicate? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/101272/2995

Comment: That question has one crappy answer about SOQL

Comment: Do you really need all of them? I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all of them requires use of the Metadata API. You can access a known one via Javascript, however, by just merging it in. Escaping recommended.

```
var mylabel = "{!JSINHTMLENCODE($Label.MyLabel)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this. In one remote action, you get all custom labels and put them in a map with key - value pair like below code:

```
Map<String, String> customLabelMap = new Map<String, String>();
map.put('ActionNotFound', Label.ActionNotFound);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: This would still require me to type each an every label by hand. We have over 1000 custom labels and I am looking to see if there is a way to do this dynamically

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend to check the link, provided by @Adrian Larson